# C++'ish idiom for setting core affinity?

Tags: c++, boost, multicore, idioms, affinity

Consider the following code:

```
cpu_set_t cpuset; 

CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(0, &cpuset);
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);
```

this sets the processor affinity of a process - the cores on which it is allowed to be scheduled basically. It uses the [GNU C library facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Affinity.html) (but I'm not sure it's supported on all OSes where glibc is supported). Now, I'm pretty certain the C++ standard library doesn't offer a similar facility, but - what is a common, more C++'ish idiom for doing the same thing?

Comment: There simply isn't any. C++ just doesn't deal with this.

Comment: Under Linux, for setting your process' affinity to a specific core or cores range, consider using taskset. e.g. `taskset ./main -c 0-1` for restricting `main` to cores 0 and 1

Comment: @Daniel: Does this invoke `./main`, or apply to future invocations?

Comment: [`taskset`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) runs your next command with the specified cpu mask. It does only apply to that specific command instance.
If you want to apply the binding every single time you run your program, you should go with `sched_setaffinity` or `pthread_setaffinity_np`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in the C++ standard library. Also, note that there is no such functionality in the C standard library either. It is provided by glibc, but not in its role as the C standard library: it's a part of Linux, not of the C standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: You're saying glibc doesn't actually support this on other Unix'ish operating systems? Or on Windows?

Comment: @einpoklum The [`sched_setaffinity`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) function is Linux-specific. It's not part of Windows, POSIX, or any other standard. Other operating systems will most likely have their own variants though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ... ok, and there's nothing standard-ish which wraps those OS-specific calls.